# ncurses - input/output on the same line

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

```c
nocbreak();
echo();
mvwprintw(game->prompt, 1, 0, "Move from? ");
wgetnstr(game->prompt, input, 4);
wgetch(game->prompt);

/* find first not empty character and set cursor on it */
wmove(game->prompt, 1, getmaxx(game->prompt) - 1);
while ((winch(game->prompt) & A_CHARTEXT) == ' ')
    wmove(game->prompt, 1, getcurx(game->prompt) - 1);
wmove(game->prompt, 1, getcurx(game->prompt) + 2);

wprintw(game->prompt, "To? ");
wgetnstr(game->prompt, input, 4);
```

This is the only solution I have found. I wonder if there is easier way to discard the newline so I's possible to easily call multiple `wgetnstr` or any other IO function on the same line. I tried reading with `getch` but it didn't help.

In other words:

I want to read input on **the same line** like this `Move from? <input1> To? <input2>` without using hacks like the one above to mitigate the newline from `<input1>`. Just call the IO function after each other (I tried different modes like `nonl()`, `nl()` but it seems they don't affect the user input).

Here is how the **default** behavior looks for reference:

code

```c
getstr(input)
printw("Hello")
```

behavior

```
my input here
Hello
```

**expected** behavior

```
my input hereHello
```

edit:
here is my current solution as suggested by @n.m.couldbeanAI

```c
int
wread(WINDOW *win, char *input, int maxlen)
{
    int ch;
    char *beg = input;
    doupdate();
    curs_set(1);
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    keypad(win, TRUE);
    while ((ch = wgetch(win)) != '\n') {
        switch (ch) {
        case KEY_BACKSPACE:
            if (input - beg <= 0) continue;
            wmove(win, getcury(win), getcurx(win) - 1);
            wdelch(win);
            input--;
            break;
        default:
            if (input - beg >= maxlen) continue;
            waddch(win, ch);
            *(input++) = ch;
            break;
        }
    }
    curs_set(0);
    return input - beg;
}
```

Comment: I think it might help the community if you could please share some output as it is and the output as you wish it.  It's not totally clear to me what the trouble is; maybe others are thinking the same?  Thanks and best wishes.

Comment: @gregspears I edited the question, I'm not native english speaker so I'm sometimes have trouble communicating my problems but I hope this helps.

Comment: I would write a simple little line editor based on `wgetch` and present a bit nicer UX than the dumb Unix "your editing key is backspace" style line input.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI so you suggest i should call noecho() and do all printing of the user input myself? My main issue relates to this annoying newline character.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI for now i will try your solution, thanks

Comment: Yes, why not? It's a good exercise, not too difficult, and in the end it can be a reusable library.

Comment: @yan3ku -- yes -- your edit to the question really helped make clear.  And now looks like you got some good help in the comments too -- very nice.